# Custom block-wise matrix

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, projection-matrices

I have two block matrices $A$ and $B$ defined as:

\begin{align}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13} & A_{14} \\
A_{21} & A_{22} & A_{23} & A_{24} \\
A_{31} & A_{32} & A_{33} & A_{34}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
B = 
\begin{pmatrix}
I & I & 0 & 0 \\
0 & I & I & 0 \\
0 & I & 0 & I
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

where $I$ and $0$ are the identity and zero matrices, respectively. Is there a way to find a express a block matrix $C$, from $A$ and $B$, where $C$ is defined as
\begin{align}
C= 
\begin{pmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{12} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & A_{22} & A_{23} & 0 \\
0 & A_{32} & 0 & A_{34}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
I'm looking for a function of the following format $C= f(A, B)$.

Comment: It's unclear what kind of function you are looking for. But you can notice that the columns of $C$ are not in general linear combinations of the columns of $A$. If the $I$ matrices of $B$ were replaced with $J$ matrices (matrices of *all* ones), then you could get $C$ from the Hadamard product of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @xxxxxxxxx: thanks for your comment, this helps a lot!